# How to print a line only if it contains a specific string using groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, devops

I have a Jenkins log file and I want to print the lines that contain the string `"FOUND"` on it.

How to achieve that using Groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this and comments in-line.

```
//Change log file name in below statement
def lines = new File('/tmp/test123.txt').readLines()
//Get the list of matching lines
def result = lines.findAll { it.contains('FOUND') }
println result*.toString()
```